# How to align the boxes so that the space between them would be equal?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment

Aligning vertical centers:

[image]

Aligning horizontal centers:

[image]

How to align the boxes so that the space between them would be equal?

[image]

Comment: Because you only have one gap between rows of boxes, this is impossible without changing either the overall length or the overall height. You don't have enough spaces to distribute.

Comment: Do you mean, you want the vertical gap to be the same as the horizontal gap? Since they're squares, I'd rotate a pair then  align to that.

Comment: Semi-related, [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/) might help. You can establish your spacing in guides, then snap objects to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do a little maths. There's no way to say align objects vertically based on how they're horizontally aligned.
If, for e.g., your boxes are 10mm and the gap 2mm, and the first box starts at 0x,0y then the second box starts at 12, the second at 24 (3rd at 36, etc.).
Just calculate where the last box sits (whether you have just 3 or 300), position it there by changing it's x and y coordinates , select all the boxes in the row/column and then align to centres. Then do the same vertically.

Comment: That's a great idea. But what if the size of boxes are not equal?

Answer (score 2):

Now while that's an okay answer, I was - of course - not thinking. 
The better way to do this is to select all the objects in the Row or Column, click a second time on your first item in the row - to make it your Key Object (it'll then have a 'thick' selected blue border and everything will align to this one). Then in your `Align` Palette type in what the gap between the objects should be. For e.g. 2 mm
This way you don't need to do any maths.

[image]

(That should help for your question if the boxes aren't equal sizes.)

Comment: I don't see distribute spacing (using cs4)

Comment: Hmmm, can't remember if it was in CS4 but should be. In your Align Palette click the little pull down menu in the top right corner and click on Show Options.

Comment: There is no align palette but property bar from which I can align

Comment: Yeah, the 'Distribute Spacing' doesn't show up in the property bar. Your 'Align Palette' is under 'Window > Align' or Shift + F7

Comment: No. I mean Align Palette isn't there in cs4.

Comment: Erm - which CS4 software are you using? Illustrator, InDesign, Photoshop?

Comment: Ah. Then the first answer I posted is the only way to do it. (I was under the impression we were in Illustrator - my apologies.)